# Как исправить такое различие разметки ? Android7 (api25+) и Android 4.1(api16) (Java-Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Wave time"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="25dp"
        android:maxHeight="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:thumb="@drawable/success_normal_small"
        android:splitTrack="false"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_style"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=" Intensity"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minHeight="25dp"
        android:maxHeight="25dp"
        android:thumb="@drawable/success_normal_small"
        android:splitTrack="false"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_style"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="stop"
            android:text="Stop"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="tr"
            android:text="Start"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />



    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

seek_style.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ff747674"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                    android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                    android:angle="270"
                    />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#ff0099CC"
                    android:centerColor="#ff3399CC"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#ff6699CC"
                    android:angle="270"
                    />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: проблема скорее не в API, а в dpi экрана. Навскидку: `5dip` измените на `5dp` и уберите у `SeekBar` вес

Comment: В SeekBar  убрал вес сработало.